# Understanding Self within a trait impl

Tags: rust

Im a bit confused by self. Could you please help me along?? Im trying to append or push a new value into the `vec`. This only shows me that I have no idea what self actually is. The error I'm getting is :

```
---- ^^^^ this call modifies `self` in-place
   |         |
   |         you probably want to use this value after calling the method...
   = note: ...instead of the `()` output of method `push`
```

Why does the following work but...

```
trait AppendBar {
    fn append_bar(self) -> Self;
}

impl AppendBar for String {
    fn append_bar(self) -> Self{
        self.to_string() + "Bar"
    }
}
```

this and...

```
impl AppendBar for Vec<String> {
    fn append_bar(self) -> Self{
        let mut bar = vec![String::from("Bar")];

        bar.push(self);

        bar
    }
}
```

this and...

```
impl AppendBar for Vec<String> {
    fn append_bar(self) -> Self{
        let bar_vec = vec!["Bar".to_string()];

        self.append(bar_vec)
    }
}
```

this do not?

```
trait AppendBar<T> {
    fn append_bar(self) -> Self;
}

impl<T> AppendBar<T> for Vec<T> {
    fn append_bar(self) -> Self{    
        self.push("Bar".to_string())    
    }
}
```

Comment: cause push doesn't return anything

Comment: If you answer the question Ill give it to you

Answer (score 2):

```
impl AppendBar for Vec<String> {
    fn append_bar(self) -> Self{
        let mut bar = vec![String::from("Bar")];
        bar.push(self);
        bar
    }
}
```

Because `self` is a `Vec<String>` and you can't push a `Vec<String>` into a `Vec<String>` (which the error message tells you: "Expected `String` got `Vec<String>`").

```
impl AppendBar for Vec<String> {
    fn append_bar(self) -> Self{
        let bar_vec = vec!["Bar".to_string()];
        self.append(bar_vec)
    }
}
```

Because [`Vec::append`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.append) doesn't return anything, so you need to return `self` yourself (or take `&mut self` as parameter and return nothing).

```
impl<T> AppendBar<T> for Vec<T> {
    fn append_bar(self) -> Self{    
        self.push("Bar".to_string())    
    }
}
```

Because `"Bar".to_string()` is not guaranteed to be a `T` for all types `T`.